# How to Make Your Computer Change Java Path

Tags: java, file, directory

So a while back I installed some .jar files for game mods, which seems to have installed the 1.8 JRE on my computer. Now, I installed JDK 14, however, my computer still thinks that my Java version is 1.8. I have two Java folders on my computer - one in Program Files with the JDK, and one in Program Files (x86) with the old JRE.

I set the JAVA_HOME environment variable to the directory of the JDK but when I type `java -version` in my Command Prompt it still says 1.8. How do I get my computer to run Java from JDK 14?

*Apologies if this doesn't make much sense, I still don't know much about how computers work.

Comment: This is operating system specific. I'm not sure if this site wants this question, but at a minimum you need to tell people what OS and what version you're running.

Comment: Because it's about `PATH`, not `JAVA_HOME`.

Comment: @JoshuaD, they're using Windows.

Comment: For windows, you want `PATH` the one with the list of all the `.exe` files on your system.  Instructions: https://www.java.com/en/download/help/path.xml

Comment: Also this link from SO's sister site: https://superuser.com/questions/284342/what-are-path-and-other-environment-variables-and-how-can-i-set-or-use-them

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are using Windows based on Program Files (x86) folder. Let say it is Windows 10.

Go to environment variable, system variables section.

1. change `CLASS` value to ...\java14\bin
2. change `classpath` value to ...\java14\lib\ *.jar
3. change `JAVA_HOME` value to ...\java14
4. change `PATH` value to ...\java14\bin (be sure to move this up to the top)

Substitute the name of your *jdk* folder to *java14*
Now it should perform as expected. `javac` will be version 14, `java` will be version 14 too.