# JAVA_HOME on Windows seems to have no effect

Tags: java, windows, powershell, cmd, java-home

I have three different JDKs on my system so I can appropriately switch between projects. Importing the appropriate JDK in my IDE is no issue, but the command line is. See, despite the fact that `JAVA_HOME` for both my user as well as the system point to `jre1.8.0_261`:

[image: My system variables]

`java --version` seems to still think that my default is Amazon's Corretto JDK, which I only need for one specific project:

```
C:\Users\jasonfil>java --version
openjdk 11.0.8 2020-07-14 LTS
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Corretto-11.0.8.10.1 (build 11.0.8+10-LTS)
```

This is also true for Powershell. I have also tried in both `cmd` **and** Powershell as administrator. Same issue.

Curiously, when I query the environment variable from `cmd`, I get the intended JDK:

```
C:\Users\jasonfil>echo %JAVA_HOME%
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_261
```

While on Powershell, `echo` just outputs the string `%JAVA_HOME` literally:

```
PS C:\Users\jasonfil> echo %JAVA_HOME%
%JAVA_HOME%
```

My goal is to be able to switch between Java versions at will, like the `update-alternatives` mechanism does in UNIX-based systems. Any ideas?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63910493/how-to-make-your-computer-change-java-path/63910723#63910723 Does this answer your question?

Comment: There is no reason to have `JAVA_HOME` listed with the same value `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_261` under both the User and System environments. As the user environment takes precedence over the system, I would generally suggest removing the entry under System. However, my general rule of thumb is that the User environment should only contain value paths which are in the users own profile tree, or for which other users should not have access. You'll need to decide for yourself which of the two to delete. BTW, in PowerShell you'd access a variable as `$Env:JAVA_HOME` not `%JAVA_HOME%`.

Comment: The current answers have covered this, but just to be clear:  Java does not use the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable *at all.*  Various tools will use that variable, such as IDEs and build tools, but Java itself does not care about that variable and does not read it.  The location of java.exe, just like any other executable program, is determined by your `Path` environment variable.

Comment: Please take a look on [What is the reason for "X is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file"?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41461002/3074564) It explains in full detail how `cmd.exe` and also `powershell.exe` (and `cscript.exe` and `wscript.exe` and many other applications and Windows functions) find an executable or script file specified without path and without file extension.

Comment: All fixed using the accepted answer and these comments. Many thanks.

Answer (score 3):

**All the outputs you are getting are as expected**.

1. `JAVA_HOME` has nothing to do with the Java version. It is simply a variable that conventionally most of the Java-based software (e.g. Web & App servers, IDEs etc.) use to refer to find the JDK installation. Therefore, you should set it to the base folder of JDK e.g. `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_261`.
2. `java -version` looks for `java.exe` which is inside the `bin` folder of the JDK installation e.g. `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_261\bin`. Therefore, `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_261\bin` should be one of the values in your `PATH` variable. If you have already set `JAVA_HOME` as mentioned above, setting up the path of `java.exe` becomes easier as you can set `%JAVA_HOME%\bin` instead of `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_261\bin` in your `PATH` variable.
3. `echo %JAVA_HOME%` will return you the value set in your `JAVA_HOME` variable. Similarly, if you use `echo %PATH%`, you will get the values set in your `PATH` variable.

**Note:** You are not provided with a JRE starting with Java-11.

Answer (score 3):

Java doesn't use the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable. Some tools do, especially during installation of the tools, but that's different.

Java doesn't even need to be on the `PATH`, but it is certainly more convenient if it is.

The question shows that there is a Java installed at `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_261`.

It also shows that there is an OpenJDK 11.0.8 somewhere, but doesn't show where, so for this answer, we'll pretend it was installed/unzipped to `C:\foo\openjdk-11.0.8`.

The `java` executable is in the `bin` folder, so to show that the `PATH` and `JAVA_HOME` doesn't matter, run the `java` command fully qualified. On my machine, I get the following outputs *(with different actual paths and I have different versions, but whatever)*:

```
C:\>"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_261\bin\java" -version
java version "1.8.0_181"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_181-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.181-b13, mixed mode)
```

```
C:\>C:\foo\openjdk-11.0.8\bin\java -version
openjdk version "11.0.2" 2019-01-15
OpenJDK Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.2+9)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.2+9, mixed mode)
```

Running `java` unqualified is of course easier, so add the `bin` folder of Java you want to the **front** of the `PATH`. You can even do that in a command prompt to change the "default" Java for that command prompt without affecting your "global default" as specified in that environment property dialog.

You can keep doing it in the same command prompt, if needed, to flip back and forth, but you'd want to limit that, since the `PATH` will get longer and longer, with lots of redundant entries, the more you do it.

```
C:\>set PATH=C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_261\bin;%PATH%

C:\>java -version
java version "1.8.0_181"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_181-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.181-b13, mixed mode)

C:\>set PATH=C:\foo\openjdk-11.0.8\bin\java\bin;%PATH%

C:\>java -version
openjdk version "11.0.2" 2019-01-15
OpenJDK Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.2+9)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.2+9, mixed mode)
```

Answer (score 0):

Both cmd and Powershell will reference Path variable to check if the requested executable is in the PATH. The JAVA_HOME variable will only be used by the IDE or the Java applications. So to have the desired JDK in the path, append the JDK path to Path environment variable to either User variables (if you desire this settings should only afffect the current logged in user i.e. your login) or System Variable.

After you add these settings make sure you reopen cmd or Powershell console for the settings to take effect.

Answer (score 0):

If the PATH environment variable contains an entry for each java installation on your machine, then the console is going to always use the java installation which occurs first in the PATH environment variable.  If you want to use a specific version of java, modify the path environment variable so that version of java's bin folder is declared before any of the other installed versions of java.

Answer (score 0):

I added the environment variable and then restarted my machine worked well.